# Rspec test, about the order and before(:all)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

If I have **rspec** test like following:

```
context "main context" do

  before(:all) do
     # code for before :all
     puts "my fore :all"
  end 
  describe "Scenario-1" do
     context "my context 1" do
        it "should blablabla" do

     end
        it "should blablabla" do

     end
      end
      context "my context 2" do
        it "should blablabla" do

    end
        it "should blablabla" do

     end
      end
    end # end of describe "Scenario-1"

    describe "Scenario-2"
       context "my context 3" do
         it "should blablabla" do

     end
         it "should blablabla" do

     end
       end
    end #end of "Scenario-2"

end #end of main context
```

**Two questions to ask:**

**1.** Is it so that the `before(:all)` declare actually get called in **each sub context** ? I thought it is only called once during the whole test, but when I run my test, **What I experienced is** that the code in `before(:all)` **get executed in each** `context`, that's it get run when each `context` started, why?

(As you noticed I have "`puts`" as part of my `before(:all)` code, and **I saw this puts in each sub-context when run the test**, why? isn't `before(:all)` should only be executed once during the whole test??)

**2.** When I run my test, Why the order of the test running is **from bottom context to up context** (while inside each context, the order of "it" is up-down)? How to change the test order on context level then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) before(:all) should be running only once... but there is a known isue about it doing exactly what you've pointed out. Discussed here:
http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rspec-users/2010-September/018

2) tests must run independently of one another. to ensure that you aren't making any assumptions. Thus testing suites often run the tests in random or reverse order - to be sure that you aren't doing that.

Comment: Hi, I think I described my experience clearly, but anyhow, I updated the description. The code in before(:all) get executed when each context started. That's my question. Please check my update.

Comment: Yes, you clearly described that it's being called in each subcontext... but what is actually happening to you specifically?  can you give me an example of what you are actually putting in before(:all) that is being called in each subcontext? It's just that it's easier to solve an issue if I've got a real example to work with, rather than an abstract description.

Comment: Hi, The code inside before(:all) is Object.create(...), which just create some objects in database. Nothing special.

Comment: I ask because when I use exactly your example and put a "puts 'I'm in before all now'" in the before(:all)... it just runs once at the beginning.

So it may be something to do with *what* you're putting in the before(:all).

Comment: So... how do you know that it's being run more than once (ie in every context) what is the result?

Comment: Hi, thank you. And Why I say the code in before(:all) get executed in each sub-context is because it print out my "puts" text in each sub-context (I do have "puts" as part of my before(:all) code), and that's also why I post the question here...

Comment: And that is what i was originally asking for. :)

Interesting... when I change it from being a simple 'puts' to being an object creation, i get the same result... it runs before(:all) for every context (as though it's a before(:each)). But if I remove the object-creation.. it goes back to being run just the once. Weird

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue. I've updated my answer to include the link

Comment: I see... thank you. I suppose before(:all) is context-based, if I have a sub-context which also hold a before(:all), the sub before(:all) will get executed only once when the sub-context is running. Do you think so?

Comment: I tend not to use before(:all) anyway... I generally use before(:each) and just take the performance hit. In the case of setting up a database full of new objects - it's better, as it ensures that the db is full of a fresh, clean set of objects, rather than ones that might have changed due to another test. When using before(:each), the ones "higher up the page" get executed first, then the ones lower down... ie your main scenario, then the local describe, then the sub-context. it's the same with before(:all) (in case you're set on using it even though it's apparently broken) :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, read [this](http://rspec.info/documentation/before_and_after.html) - especially the part at the bottom of the page

secondly, a trick I learned recently is that you can use `after(:all)`

```
after :all do
  @users.each { |user| user.destroy! }
end
```

Pretty neat

Comment: ps, you need to use `before(:each)` and not `before(:all)`